# How to import numpy through xlwings package? "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, excel, vba, numpy, xlwings

I'm trying to use the 'Run Python' function of xlwings to run Python code through VBA.

I have been using Spyder to execute my code and it runs with no errors.

When trying to run this from VBA with the xlwings package I receive:

> "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

and this error relates to the numpy package.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the anaconda package and using `pip install numpy`.

I checked that I have the most up to date version of xlwings 0.15.8.

I found this thread https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/954 stating this issue was fixed with version 0.15.7 of xlwings.

VBA code:

```vb
RunPython ("import Demand; Demand.calibrate_Demand()")
```

Spyder code:

```
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMAResults
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime

def calibrate_dDemand():
```

My Python file is called Demand.py

When executing my VBA code I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "e:\julia\calibration automation\Demand.py", line 17, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

If I place `import pandas as pd` first (before importing numpy) I receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "e:\julia\calibration automation\Demand.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1127

Comment: I have the same issue, I don't think the github post above helped, but if anybody has a different experience please let me know!

Comment: Yes the github post didn't help me either. I had to uninstall and then reinstall anaconda, and during the installation process, when it asks you if you'd like to set anaconda to the windows path (which isn't recommended in the setup process), I selected yes. This resolved the issue I was having with numpy/pandas. I tried various other solutions and this was the only one that worked for me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying for a couple of weeks to hit back against this problem too.
I have a company-owned laptop which is severely restricted to what environment variables I have access too, and PATH is not one of them.
I have no trouble linking Excel with Python (Spyder / Anaconda3 installation), but as soon as add `import numpy as np` to my python code, I get the same `DLL load failed` error. (It didn't always do this though, it just started doing it overnight for no reason I can fathom, but I digress). The code itself works fine in Spyder though.
I did eventually find something of a workaround though, but it's a bit of a last resort, being more than a bit awkward and daft. Maybe useful for a developer to track down a more sensible solution though?
Anyway, I found that if I launched Excel from Spyder, the numpy module correctly imports, and remains stable. To do this, I just access the contents of one of the workbook's cells without having Excel already open. This launches Excel, opens the workbooks, and correctly imports numpy.
What do you think?